# piping stdout into other program stdin fails; no message go through the pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I'm trying to program a shell with a fork and a pipe in C.
I've tried to fork my process into to 2 and make the son speak with its parent:
stdout to be the stdin of the child.
I thought implementing it via a pipe.
Here is my try:

```
void split(){

int fork_id = fork();

int pipes[2];
 pipe(pipes);

if (fork_id) {
    //parent

   dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipes[0]);
    close(pipes[1]);
} else {
    //child


     dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipes[0]);
    close(pipes[1]);
}
}
```

Afterwards I run software with execvp (they run with the right argv [ I checked it])/
Unfortunately the 2nd program doesn't get the output of the first, it seems to be that it gets "".
Can anyone spot the mistake?

Comment: For one thing, `pipe` needs to be called before `fork`.

Comment: Please also extract a [mcve] and provide that here. Also, you don't say what you observed, only your interpretation. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: thanks @kaylum. It works.

Answer (score 1):

credit to @kalyum.
I forked before creating the pipe, therefore each process had its own pipe.
therefore no connection was established between the 2.